# Trying to modify PHP code to identify and define a link as an image so I can display it using my script

Tags: javascript, php, mime-types

Pardon me if some of the terminology I use is unorthodox, I'm still learning the ropes of working with code.

I have a phpbb forum and I'm in the process of compensating for all the middle aged tech challenged who have a tough time figuring out how to use bbcode buttons to insert images/tweets/videos etc...

So far I've taken my limited html/css skills and been able to figure out just enough javascript (with the help of some very polite people here) to get it going.

Using oembed, I've got most media embedded, and this javascript code which converts img links to embedded images

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.postlink.img-link').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).html($('<img>').attr('src', href)).colorbox({photo: true, scalePhotos:'true', fixed:true, maxWidth: '99%', maxHeight: '99%'});
    });
})
```

I piggybacked off this modification (I had installed several years ago which which defined img-links based on the extensions of a.postlinks).  Since the php already separated img url's it was easy to add a script which displayed the img (and then opens in a colorbox if clicked).

My thinking was to alter the php code to expand the function for defining image links beyond just extensions.  So many image url's don't end with .jpg or png (for example http://www.trbimg.com/img-561141b1/turbine/ct-khalil-mack-assignment-bears-preview-spt-1004-20151002), I need a better method to determine what's actually an image.

```
// Link classes
define('INTERNAL_LINK_CLASS', 'postlink-local');
define('EXTERNAL_LINK_CLASS', 'postlink');

// Link file types (separate file extensions with a vertical bar "|")
define('PDF_LINK_TYPES', 'pdf');
define('IMG_LINK_TYPES', 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp');
define('ZIP_LINK_TYPES', 'zip|rar|7z');

// Special cases for specific link types. Separate file extensions with a vertical bar (|).
define('EXTERNAL_LINK_TYPES', '');          // Example 1: 'pdf|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|zip|rar|7z'
define('INTERNAL_LINK_TYPES', '');          // Example 2: PDF_LINK_TYPES . '|' . IMG_LINK_TYPES . '|' . ZIP_LINK_TYPES
define('SKIP_LINK_TYPES', '');              // Don't process links to these file types
define('SKIP_PREFIX_TYPES', '');            // Don't add an external link prefix for these file types

// Link classes for specific file types.
global $link_type_classes;
$link_type_classes = array(
    PDF_LINK_TYPES  => 'pdf-link',
    IMG_LINK_TYPES  => 'img-link',
    ZIP_LINK_TYPES  => 'zip-link',
);
```

I've tried modifying the php code, but I'm very limited in my php experience and it seems I break the board when I try to get too frisky.

I've tried this:

```
function identifyImage($filename) {
    if (!($handle = fopen($filename, 'rb')))
        throw new Exception('Error opening '.$filename);

    $hdr = fread($handle, 12);
    fclose($handle);
    switch (strtolower(substr($filename, -4))) {
        "\xff\xd8\xff" => 'img-link',
        "\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a" => 'img-link',
        "II*\x00" => 'img-link',
        "MM\x00*" => 'img-link',
        "\x00\x00\x01\x00" => 'img-link',
        "\x00\x00\x02\x00" => 'img-link',
        "GIF89a" => 'img-link',
        "GIF87a" => 'img-link',
        "BM" => 'img-link',
    }
}
```

Nothing.

I've tried this:

```
function identifyImage($filename) {
    if (!($handle = fopen($filename, 'rb')))
        throw new Exception('Error opening '.$filename);

    $hdr = fread($handle, 12);
    fclose($handle);
    switch (strtolower(substr($filename, -4))) {
        case '.jpg':
            if ((substr($hdr, 0, 4) == "\xff\xd8\xff\xe0") && (substr($hdr, 6, 5) == "JFIF\x00"))
                return 'jpg';
        case '.png':
            if (substr($hdr, 0, 8) == "\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a")
                return 'png';
        case '.gif':
            if ((substr($hdr, 0, 6) == 'GIF87a') || (substr($hdr, 0, 6) == 'GIF89a'))
                return 'gif';
        case '.psd':
            if (substr($hdr, 0, 4) == '8BPS')
                return 'psd';
        case '.tif':
            if ((substr($hdr, 0, 4) == "MM\x00*") || (substr($hdr, 0, 4) == "II*\x00")) 
                return 'tif';
        case '.bmp':
            if ($hdr[0].$hdr[1] == 'BM')
                return 'bmp';
        default:
            return False;
    }
}
```

Once again nothing.  Would someone be kind enough to guide me to the right usage of this code to be able to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: why are you doing manual file detection? there's [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) to do all of that for you already.

Comment: it's like reinventing the WHEEL, just use available libraries. e.g. fileinfo

Comment: Because I'm a dummy.  Can somebody point me in the right direction to get me going?  I'm not asking to have it done for me, I'm willing to put in the work, but not exactly sure where to look.  This probably seems elementary to a lot of you, but I'm struggling with it.

Comment: I've tried adding $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);

Comment: I'm just getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open()